# One to many with applicationuser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

If this is a dupp, by all means direct me to the answer.

ASP.NET, MVC5, EF6

Each application user can have many TfsAccountCredentials

IdentityModel.cs has the following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<TfsAccountCredentials> TfsAccountCredentials { get; set; }
}
```

TfsAccountCredentials.cs has the following:

```
public class TfsAccountCredentials
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //other properties

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

}
```

TfsAccountCredentialsDb has the following:

```
public class TfsAccountCredentialsDb : DbContext
{
    public TfsAccountCredentialsDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TfsAccountCredentials> TfsAccountCredentials { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TfsAccountCredentials>()
            .HasRequired(ac => ac.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(ac => ac.TfsAccountCredentials)
            .HasForeignKey(ac => ac.ApplicationUserId);
    }
}
```

IdentityDb.cs has the following:

```
public class IdentityDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Two things.  First, when I add a migration using the Identity context, part of the script it generates adds the TfsAccountCredentials table, which already exists due to an earlier migration for the TfsAccountCredentials context.

Second, when I add a migration using the TfsAccountCredentials context, I get the following error:

```
TfsTeamStatus.Web.DataContexts.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
TfsTeamStatus.Web.DataContexts.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

**EDIT**
My final solution:

IdentityModel.cs contains the following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<TfsAccountCredentials> TfsAccountCredentials { get; set; }
}
```

TfsAccountCredentials.cs contains the following:

```
public class TfsAccountCredentials
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //other properties

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

}
```

ApplicationDb.cs contains the following:

```
public class ApplicationDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TfsAccountCredentials> TfsAccountCredentials { get; set; }

}
```

So TfsAccountCredentialsDb.cs and IdentityDb.cs got combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are making to separate DB? I think you want make 2 table in **same** DB not different DB so remove your `TfsAccountCredentialsDb` and add your `TfsAccountCredentials` to `IdentityDb`:

```
public class IdentityDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<TfsAccountCredentials> TfsAccountCredentials { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I'm not creating a separate DB.  I can have two different data context classes, but go to the same DB and just have them create different tables.Note that the default ctor for IdentityDb.cs and TfsCredentialsDb.cs both have the same connection string.  I know this works because it was successfully creating the tables in the same DB before I tried to link to the entities.

Comment: But each `DbContext` generates separate DB. If you are saying EF puts 2 DB to one DB because of same connection string it dose not mean this is a good idea. EF sees your DB 2 different DB and don't work as you want. Source of your problems is this actually. Consider my solution it is workaround your problems.

Comment: So you very well may be right.  The interesting thing is that I did this based off of a PluralSight video by Scott Allen (ASP.NET MVC Fundamentals).  He splits it out into two contexts to show how you can control have different migrations for each one, but they both go to the same db.  He wasn't linking his entities to his users though, so maybe that's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `IdentityDb` because `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` is the context that handles Identity issues. So then you can either:

A) Have `TfsAccountCredentialsDb` inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. This will allow you to reference ApplicationUser in your models. The DbSet for ApplicationUser is in the base class you can't see.

B) If you want `TfsAccountCredentialsDb`  to inherit from `DbContext`, then you will have to add a copy of `ApplicationUser` in that context along with it's `DbSet` that you can use to reference within your app's context.

Comment: IdentityDb is the given by default with a new ASP.NET MVC project.  It's originally called ApplicationDbContext; I just renamed it.

Comment: The main point is that with 2 contexts they will not see each others DbSets. Whether they're in the same database or not makes no difference. This line ".HasRequired(ac => ac.ApplicationUser)" requires a DbSet<ApplicationUser> in your TfsAccountCredentialsDb  context.

Comment: Interesting...thanks Steve.  Between you and Sam, I think I'm wrapping my head around this.